# My Samsung series 5 laptop's mouse is stuck on one spot and keeps clicking

Tags: linux, mouse, touchpad

I have a Samsung series 5 ultratouch laptop with Linux installed.

Today my mouse just got stuck at the bottom middle of the screen and kept clicking every second.

I tried rebooting the laptop, I tried reinstalling Linux Mint I even tried installing Ubuntu to see if its a cinnamon problem but still no joy. So this led me to believe that it is a hardware problem (I seriously hope not). So I decided to disable the touch pad from BIOS but that didn't help either. The only thing that works is to hold my finger on the touch screen and that makes the mouse behave.

It's really strange and I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem

Comment: Remove and reinstall the touchpad drivers?

Comment: I already tried that, it doesn’t work and I fear its a hardware problem too, I was just hoping it wasn't.